# Botão registrar para o aplicativo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app, button

Estou desenvolvendo um app e ele tem registro e login de usuários, eu fiz boa parte já, porém toda vez que clico no botão para registrar usuário, o aplicativo para, alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue o código.

Código da Classe para Registrar

```
public class Registrar extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declarando EditTexts
    EditText txtNomeReg;
    EditText txtEmailReg;
    EditText txtSenhaReg;

    //Declara InputsLayout
    TextInputLayout InNomeReg;
    TextInputLayout InEmailReg;
    TextInputLayout InSenhaReg;

    //Declarando botão
    Button btnRegistrar;

    //Declarando SQL
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;

    //Metodo usuado para conectar XML a seus objetos
    private void initView(){

        txtNomeReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNomeReg);
        txtEmailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailReg);
        txtSenhaReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSenhaReg);
        InNomeReg = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.InNomeReg);
        InEmailReg = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.InEmailReg);
        InSenhaReg = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.InSenhaReg);
        btnRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar);
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        initView();
        txtVoltarReg();
        btnRegistrar();
    }



    //Validar entrada entrada do usuário
    public boolean valida(){
        boolean valido = false;

        //Obtem valores dos campos Inputs
        String nomeUsuario = txtNomeReg.getText().toString();
        String email = txtEmailReg.getText().toString();
        String senha = txtSenhaReg.getText().toString();

        //Validando campo usuario
        if (nomeUsuario.isEmpty()){
            valido = false;
            InNomeReg.setError("Por favor insira um usuário válido!");
        } else {
            if (nomeUsuario.length()>5){
                valido = true;
                InNomeReg.setError(null);
            } else {
                valido = false;
                InNomeReg.setError("Nome de usuário muito curto");
            }
        }

        //Validação para o campo email
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            valido = false;
            InEmailReg.setError("Por favor insira um email válido");
        } else {
            valido = true;
            InEmailReg.setError(null);
        }

        //Validação para o campo senha
        if (senha.isEmpty()){
            valido = false;
            InSenhaReg.setError("Insira um senha válida!");
        } else {
            if (senha.length()>5){
                valido = true;
                InSenhaReg.setError(null);
            } else {
                valido = false;
                InSenhaReg.setError("Senha muito curta!");
            }
        }

        return valido;

    }



    public void btnRegistrar() {
        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (valida()){
                    String nomeUsuario = txtNomeReg.getText().toString();
                    String email = txtEmailReg.getText().toString();
                    String senha = txtSenhaReg.getText().toString();

                    //Checa no bando de dados se existe algum usuário associado a esse email
                    if (!sqliteHelper.ValidaEmail(email)){

                        sqliteHelper.addUser(new Usuarios(null, nomeUsuario, email, senha));
                        Snackbar.make(btnRegistrar, "Usuário criado! Faça Login", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else{
                        Snackbar.make(btnRegistrar, "E-mail já cadastrado", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }



    private void txtVoltarReg() {
        TextView btnProximo = findViewById(R.id.txtVoltarReg);
        btnProximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent Registrar = new Intent(Registrar.this, Logar.class);
                startActivity(Registrar);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Código da Classe do banco de dados

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Nome do banco de dados
    public static final String BANCO_DADOS = "keyssword.db";

    //Versão do banco de dados
    public static final int VERSAO_BANDODADOS = 1;

    //Nome da tabela
    public static final String TABELA_USUARIOS = "usuarios";

    //********Campos da tabela de usuários********//

    //Coluna de ID, Chave primária
    public static final String ID = "id";

    //Coluna de nome de usuário
    public static final String NOME_USUARIO = "nomeusuario";

    //Coluna E-mail
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";

    //Coluna senha
    public static final String SENHA = "senha";

    //SQL para criar tabela de usuários
    public static final String SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_USUARIOS
            + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + NOME_USUARIO + "TEXT, " + EMAIL + "TEXT, "
            + SENHA + "TEXT" + " ) ";

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABELA_USUARIOS, null, VERSAO_BANDODADOS);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        //Cria uma tabela quando o onCreate é chamado
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int il) {

        //Descarta a tabela para criar uma nova,
        // se a versão do banco de dados for maior
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_USUARIOS);
    }

    //Esse método é responsavel por adicionar usuários à tabela
    public void addUser(Usuarios usuario) {

        //Abre o banco de dados para gravação
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Cria os valores de conteúdo para inserir
        ContentValues inserir = new ContentValues();

        //Coloca o nome de usuário em values
        inserir.put(NOME_USUARIO, usuario.nomeUsuario);

        //Coloca o emial em values
        inserir.put(EMAIL, usuario.email);

        //Coloca a senha em values
        inserir.put(SENHA, usuario.senha);

        //Inserir linha
        //long todo_id = db.insert(TABELA_USUARIOS, null, values);
    }


    public Usuarios ValidaUsuario(Usuarios usuario) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Seleciona a tabela
        Cursor cursor = db.query(/*Seleciona a tabela*/ TABELA_USUARIOS,
                new String[]{ID, NOME_USUARIO, EMAIL, SENHA},/*Seleciona as colunas para a query*/
                EMAIL + "=?",
                new String[]{usuario.email},
                null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0){
            Usuarios user = new Usuarios(cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3));

            if (usuario.senha.equalsIgnoreCase(user.senha)){
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean ValidaEmail(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABELA_USUARIOS,
                new String[]{ID, NOME_USUARIO,EMAIL,SENHA},
                EMAIL + "+?",
                new String[] {email},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Se precisarem do código de mais alguma parte é só dizer, preciso muito de ajuda.

Conforme solicitado, segue o log de erro.

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9e597880: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e597880: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e629670)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e597880: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e629670)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e597880: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e629670)
W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3012 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=53KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=53KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
    JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
    Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=107KB, data=64KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=82KB, data=39KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e597880: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e629670)
W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3132 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=77KB
    After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=77KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=250KB, data=164KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=177KB, data=116KB
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: nomeusuario
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gnd.keyssword, PID: 5569
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nomeusuario (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, nomeusuario, email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email+?
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.SqliteHelper.ValidaEmail(SqliteHelper.java:108)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.Registrar$1.onClick(Registrar.java:121)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Olá Gabriel! Seja bem vindo! Edite a pergunta e insira o log de erro que é mostrado no android studio.

Comment: Não dá erro no Android Studio, e sim quando testo a aplicação no meu dispositivo, no caso devo testar no Virtual Device para pegar um log de erro?

Comment: Você testa a aplicação conectado o computador ao dispositivo junto com o android studio? Se sim.. O log de erros será mostrado lá.

Comment: Não deu para colocar todo o log, ultrapassa o limite, mas acho que é necessário só essa parte aí, pois é a unica parte que deu erro.

Comment: Tranquilo, já vi o erro...

Comment: Então só tenho que adicionar um espaço antes da palavra e depois das aspas?

Comment: Vou inserir na resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Está lá Gabriel!

Comment: Se funcionar, não esquece de aprovar a reposta ok?

Comment: Testei e funcionou, aprovei já, muito obrigado. Aliás, vou abrir outro tópico, pois quando mando executar a aplicação para testa-lá, aparece duas nós dispositivo.

Comment: estou com esse outro probleminha, se puder ajudar também, fico muito grato. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372638/tela-de-login-trava-o-aplicativo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na criação da tabela.

O erro diz que não existe a coluna **nomeusuario** no banco

> no such column: nomeusuario

A sua String está sendo concatenada de forma errada aqui:

```
public static final String SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_USUARIOS
        + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + NOME_USUARIO + "TEXT, " + EMAIL + "TEXT, "
        + SENHA + "TEXT" + " ) ";
```

Do jeito que está ai ela é transformada em:

```
      " CREATE TABLE usuarios " + 
      " ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "nomeusuarioTEXT, emailTEXT, "
                //           ^           ^     // estão grudados
                + "senhaTEXT" + " ) ";
                //     ^     aqui também
```

Basta você inserir os espaços corretamente que irá funcionar.

Não esquece de deletar e re-instalar o aplicativo.

Vai ficar assim:

```
 public static final String SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_USUARIOS
                + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + NOME_USUARIO + " TEXT, " + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                               // ^ aqui              ^ aqui
                + SENHA + " TEXT" + " ) ";
                        // ^ aqui
```